# Issue with optional usage (java 8)

Tags: java

I am trying to use stream with my code below. My problem is my return value.
This piece of code return an Optional not a boolean:

```
ogps.stream().filter(elt -> (elt.getLineNumbers() != null && !vg.getLineNumbers().isEmpty())).findFirst();
```

Can you please guide me? Thks

```
//The original code
public static boolean isOrderOk(List<OrderGroup> ogps) {
        if (ogps == null || ogps.isEmpty()) {
            return true;
        }
        for (OrderGroup elt : ogps) {
            if (elt.getLineNumbers() != null && !vg.getLineNumbers().isEmpty()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
}

//The new code with stream usage
public static boolean isOrderOk(List<OrderGroup> ogps) {
        if (ogps == null || ogps.isEmpty()) {
            return true;
        }
        return ogps.stream()
                .filter(elt -> (elt.getLineNumbers() != null && !vg.getLineNumbers().isEmpty()))
                .findFirst();
        return true;
}
```

Comment: See `anyMatch`. It is a short-circuit terminal operation made exactly for this purpose.

Comment: And if you need the value from the Optional use it's `get` method

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for something like:

```
public static boolean isOrderOk(List<OrderGroup> ogps) {
    if (ogps == null || ogps.isEmpty()) {
        return true;
    }
    return ! ogps.stream()
        .anyMatch(elt -> (elt.getLineNumbers() != null && !vg.getLineNumbers().isEmpty()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you are using `findFirst` method of `stream` class and it returns `Optional` type as you can see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--).